# How to get values which changed during node edit in node api?

Tags: 7, nodes, entities

I have a node with user entity reference field. Now I want to get newly added users id's to this node via this field in [hook_node_update](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21node%21node.api.php/function/hook_node_update/7)

What is the best way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `$node` argument to `hook_node_update` contains a `$node->original` object. With that you can identify the newly added user IDs by comparing `$node->your_user_ref_field` to `$node->original->your_user_ref_field`.